# R XLConnect: ugly format when overwriting a table

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I am writing a function whose output is an excel file and I need to overwrite the excel file if already existing (I personally don't think this is the best solution, but the person I am writing the function for wants so). I am using the XLConnect package and using `loadWorkbook(..., create=createifnot)` with a `createifnot` logical variable works perfectly, but the format of the overwritten file looks terrible. Example:

Create new file:

[image]

Overwrite old file:

[image]

The problem doesn't seem to be addressed in the XLConnect vignette.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the table in excel first with the function: `clearRange(wb, sheet = "sheetname",coords = aref2idx(c(coordinates in style:"F26:PGI29")))`. And then overwrite the cells with the new data.

sheetname = name of the sheet writing to.
coordinates  = the range in the excel file.

I hope this is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem and could not identify a solution from within R. So, here's *a* suggestion based on what I did: open the resulting file, select all rows (by clicking on the row numbers on the left hand side so that the whole row is selected), right click, select 'Row height...' and set it back to 15. It's a simple solution so long as you're not outputting too many files.